# Getting to the query string (GET request array) inside a web service in .NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, get

I'm looking to find a way to access the .net query string contained in the standard ASP.NET request object inside a web service. In other words if I set a SOAP web service to this url:

http://localhost/service.asmx?id=2

Can I access the ID Get variable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just looked for "Request" of the context in asmx file and I saw that. But I'm not sure if it is right.

```
this.Context.Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Comment: The webservice class. In this sample it is "Service";

Answer (score 7):

HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask, I guess there is no HttpContext.Current.Request ?

Answer (score 2):

While searching for the solution of the same problem i decided to take different approach.
My query string was packed with lots of variables and since I was not able to access query string data from the web service, and I also did not want to send each query string variable as a separate parameter, I prepared my web method to expect one aditional string parameter.

That parameter was **window.location** (entire url of the page) in my javascript function on .aspx page

Once I had url in my web service, the rest was quite stright forward

```
Uri myRef = new Uri(stringMyWindowLocationParameter);
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection mojQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myRef.Query);
```

Now my query string is contained inside **myRef** object and this is how I call it

```
// Instead trying to request query string like this
string myId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"];

// ... I called it like this
string myId = myRef["id"];
```

Maybe it's not the most elegant way but it solved my problem.