# Get Routedata in .asmx web service on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, routedata

I am Using ASP.NET web forms. In my application i need to be able to get to routedata of UserName in URL.

Url looks like this: `localhost/profile/MyRAndomUserNAme`

There are no problems to receive it in On_Load event like this:

```
string userName = Page.RouteData.Values["UserName"] as string;
```

But if i am in my Asmx WebService and try to receive UserName from URL, it just doesn't work. So how do i get around it?

PS: Its not a MVC project so i cant use `var userName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["UserName"];` on a view

Comment: What's "Classic ASP.NET"? Do you mean "web forms"?

Comment: Also, I suspect you're using a Page Method: a `[WebMethod]` that is `static`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done asp.net non-MVC for a while but I believe this is possible using the `Current` property of the `HttpContext` class.  The `Current` property is `static` and should be always available during a web page post back.

Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["UserName"]` to get the values you require.

Comment: See the answer by 'Scott Anderson' at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298219/getting-to-the-query-string-get-request-array-inside-a-web-service-in-net. You will need to update the web config to allow `GET` strings to be passed to your web service.